# Set category position progammatically

Tags: category, php, script

Im trying to change the order of specific categories using a php script. The script below runs fine, and im seeing the position change values in catalog_category_entity, but order is unaffected in the admin, and in the front.

```
$mageFilename = '../../app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);

//children categories of "Pro Audio"
$catOrder = array(
    70,     
    141,    
    131,    
    382     
);

$position = 1;
foreach ($catOrder as $catId) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
    if($category->getId()){
        $category->setPosition($position);
        $category->save();
        echo "Set position for ".$category->getName()." to ".$position." \n";
    } else {
        echo "Could not load product\n";
        die();
    }
    $position++;
}

echo "end\n";
```

Comment: have you multi  store? Or do an indexing

Comment: @AmitBera I flushed cache and still the same. There's a multiple store views for languages, but only one store. Setting the store 0 should avoid scope issue's no?

Comment: Please use

to

Mage::app('admin');
from:

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);

Comment: @AmitBera tried using Mage::app('admin'); instead, still the same result

Comment: @AmitBera Also reindexed, still the same

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Did @KevinSchroeder provide the right answer? If so, please select this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Amit's comment is probably the answer.  catalog_category_entity stores the position setting, but the front end does not read it from there.  The position is also stored, on a category-by-category basis in catalog_category_product.

However, the *actual* place where Magento gets the category from is via a join on catalog_category_product_index.  This index is built by running the catalog_category_product index.

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
```

Answer (score 0):

In Category::_beforeSave(), Magento sets the position for newly created categories to be 1 more than the current maximum:

```
if (!$object->getId()) {
   $object->setPosition($this->_getMaxPosition($object->getPath()) + 1);
   ...
```

The only workaround I can see is to save the category, then set the position and save it again.